# Swift SpriteKit : Create a count down with the loop or timer?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, sprite-kit

In SpriteKit is it better to use the loop or a timer to create a count down effect? I tried both and it worked but I'd like to know which is good practice?

Comment: Welcome to SO Zelda.  Please see the help section https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask to find out how to ask a good question without getting a down vote.  SO is not modeled for subjective questions that have opinionated answers.  It is strictly question and concise answer here.

Answer (score 1):

you want to use an `SKAction`:

```
  let delay: TimeInterval = 2
  let command: SKAction = .run {
    print("timer is up!")
  }
  let wait: SKAction = .wait(forDuration: delay)
  let sequence: SKAction = .sequence([wait, command])

  run(sequence)
```

Using `Timer` is not good because it runs outside of the SK loop and can cause crashes... you can use `.update()` and make your own timers, but the SKAction is a much easier way of doing it.

You can actually do the above in 1 line:

```
run(.sequence([.wait(forDuration: 2), .run({print("timer done!")})])
```